# Google Apps for non-businesses without 501(c)(3)?

Tags: google-workspace

Does Google Apps have an offering if you're a non-business but not a 501(c)(3) or is that still Google Apps for Work? What do you do on a personal site? Or, a blog for a friend?

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

At this time there are six Google Apps editions. Only Google Apps Unlimited and Google Apps for Work are available to almost anyone by a license per user fee.

## Google Apps Editions

- Google Apps Unlimited
- Google Apps for Work
- Google Apps for Education
- Google Apps for Government
- Nonprofit Edition of Google Apps
- Legacy free edition of Google Apps

## References

### General

- [Google Apps for Work - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_for_Work)

### Google Apps Administrator Help

- [Schools, nonprofits, and government agencies](https://support.google.com/a/topic/3035696?hl=en)
- [Compare Google Apps Editions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385?hl=en)
- [Google Apps for Government](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174120?hl=en)